# Haskell tuple concatenation function definition issue

Tags: haskell, types

I am trying to define a function that will concatenate two tuples of `(Int, Char)` like this:

```
tupleCat :: (Integral a, Char b )=> (a, b) ->  (a, b) -> (a, [Char])
tupleCat (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =(x1+ x2, [y1] ++ [y2])
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Type constructor `Char' used as a class ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider wrapping the integer in `Sum` and then using the monoid functions --- see the [Data.Monoid](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Monoid.html) package. Your `tupleCat` would then be `mappend`.

Comment: (classes) => (types),  there should be only class before the '=>'

Comment: @dave4420 could you post your `mappend` suggestion as an answer, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Char` is no type class, it is a type:

```
tupleCat :: (Integral a) => (a, Char) ->  (a, Char) -> (a, [Char])
tupleCat (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =(x1 + x2, [y1] ++ [y2])
```

And if you really want `Int`s and not an `Integral`, they are types, too:

```
tupleCat :: (Int, Char) ->  (Int, Char) -> (Int, [Char])
tupleCat (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =(x1+ x2, [y1] ++ [y2])
```

Further, you might consider to make this a new type and to implement the Monoid type class (as suggested in the comments). One possibility would be

```
newtype Cat = Cat (Int, String)

instance Monoid Cat where
  mempty = Cat (0, [])
  mappend (Cat (i1,s1)) (Cat (i2,s2)) = Cat (i1 + i2, s1 ++ s2)
```

With this definition `tupleCat` becomes simply `mappend`. Then you can e.g. concatenate the `Cat`s in every `Foldable` (e.g. a list). Of course I don't know your intentions, so this is just a educated guess.

Comment: Interesting that the error message calls `Char` a type constructor, which it is not...

Comment: `Char` is a type constructor that takes no parameters. Please don't confuse type constructors (e.g. `Maybe`) with value constructors (e.g. `Just` or `Maybe`).

Comment: @dave4420 - Ah, I wasn't confusing type constructors with value constructors, but I was under the impression that "type constructors" took at least one type argument. But I see from the Haskell 98 report that that's not necessarily so... I guess I was thinking of type _functions_.

Comment: Thanks for the monoid tip , I am just new to Haskell to  consume that stuff :) Its just confusing that we can define  (Integral a) but not (Char a) . I would love if some one point me to these basic ideas . Thanks again.   +1 for dave4420  Char takes no parameters :)

Answer (score 2):

Good points all around so far, but I think its worth pointing out that YOUR FUNCTION CODE IS OK!  You did, however, mess up the type signature.  Its not so much that it doesn't match your function, but that `Char` is a concrete type, not a typeclass like `Integral`, `Ord`, `Show` etc.

Others have shared the matching type signature, I want to help you get there.  Often a good, (at least) first step is to let Haskell determine the type for you.

```
Prelude> let tupleCat (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =(x1+ x2, [y1] ++ [y2])
Prelude> :t tupleCat
tupleCat :: (Num t) => (t, t1) -> (t, t1) -> (t, [t1])
```

This is a little more general than you wanted, but replace `Num` with `Integral` and `t1` with `Char` and your there.

PS - the `Monoid` idea above is a great idea and allows a lot of higher order uses. But don't be worried if it confuses you, it would've thrown me for a loop pretty badly just a few months back.

Comment: jon_darkstar , Thanks this is also working . I don't have functional programming background and just try to mess around . Its really fascinating me that you guys answered me so quickly and perfectly . You made my day :) I just wanted to be rigid in function definition like conventional way

Comment: @sak - i think you kind of missed my point.  i didnt do anything to make it work.  try your original function definition without ANY (explicit) type signature.  just `tupleCat (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =(x1+ x2, [y1] ++ [y2])` and nothing more.  it will work fine bc Haskell's typing system figures it out for you (although it comes out slightly differently than you seem to have intended)